# Javascript Object Association

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototypal-inheritance

I am currently learning Javascript and I have problem on object association.

The codes can be found in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/94ajjbur/2/.

Here I highlight some of the essential parts of my codes. 
I create a ball and a number of blocks using constructor functions. To get the ball notice it hits the blocks, I put block object as one of the input to create Ball object, like this:

`var ball = new Ball(20, 20, "#000", 2, 5, objArray);`

where objArray includes a number of block Objects and a spinner object. And I create a method of Ball object, which is ballMove() which creates a ball and moves and bounce back if it hit anything.

And I want to do the following:

1. when the ball hit the spinner, nothing happens just the ball get bounce back.
2. when the ball hit the block, the block get disappear.

Here are the essential code for block to be disappear:

In JS:

```
function Ball(width, height, color, speedX, speedY, relatedObjArray) {
     Item.call(this, width, height, color); 
     this.relatedObjArray = relatedObjArray;
     ...
}

Ball.prototype = new Item(); 

Ball.prototype.ballMove = function() {
    var relatedObjArray = this.relatedObjArray;
    ...
    setInterval(function() {
        ...
        if (relatedObj.className == "block visible") {
            relatedObj.className = "block hidden"; 
            relatedObjArray.splice(i, 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

In CSS:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The codes I wrote run perfectly. However, in order to make the block disappear, I put the code which makes the block disappear in moveBall(), which is a method inside Ball, instead of Block.

Indeed, I would like to put the code to make the block disappear inside the Block constructor function, since this is an activity relates more with Block than ball. 
I would like to create a method for Block instead. It should looks something like this:

```
Block.prototype.hiddenBall = function() {
    if (touches ball) {
        block.className = "block hidden"; 
        removeBlock in the Object Array; 
}
```

while leaving moveBall() method the capability of bouncing back only.

However, I have no idea how I can do this. Since I create the Block first, then Ball. So that I can put the Block objects as an input of Ball. So how can I do the opposite as well, putting Ball as an input of Block, so that I can make the Block disappear when it detects it is hit by the ball? OR are there any alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually recommend a slightly different method: instead of just detecting in one place or another, have an overarching method that handles everything about the game.

Create a `frame` method, that handles **everything** for one frame of movement. Something like this:

```
function updateFrame() {
    ball.ballMove();
    if(ball.isTouchingBlock) {
        ball.getTouchedBlock().className = "block hidden";
    }
}
```

This method:

- moves the ball
- checks if there's a collision
- if there is, removes the colliding block

For this to work, you also need to create another property and another method of `Ball`: `isTouchingBlock`, and `getTouchedBlock()`.

`isTouchingBlock` should be a boolean, representing whether or not the ball is touching a block in this frame. It can be updated from within the `ballMove` method.

`getTouchedBlock` needs to return the `documentElement` for the block that the ball is currently touching. You can use its return value to set the `className` on.

---

If you're set on simply detecting in the `Block` object, then you need to reverse how you create: create the Ball first *without* the array of objects, and create the blocks second with a reference to the ball. Then, move your collision-detection code to whatever point in the Block code you want it.

Comment: from your idea, I have created a new code as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/ydhs0zy1/. It looks much better now. Thanks. However, the block display hidden method still resides in Ball constructor function, (now putting into getTouchedBlock method.) Do you think it will be better if I place the display hidden method in the Block constructor function. While Ball constructor function continue to have moveBall method. Do you think it will be a better option? If so, how can I achieve it? Since I don't know how to cross reference ball object to block and at the same time block to ball object.